# Performance of monolog

Tags: php, performance, symfony

I want to write logging module in my application, the only functionalities it's gonna have are:

- saving custom logs into separate files divided by date, for example
  doing the following on `2016-01-11`:

  `Log :: error('Custom error');`

  somewhere in a controller will create a file called
  `error-2016-01-11.log` with the provided line and time.
- saving notices, warnings and errors generated by PHP execution,
  catched by exception and shutdown handlers, with the same principles
  as above (based on error-level that was catched)

---

It's pretty big application, and my question is - would using monolog bundle be better and/or faster than writing my custom code doing this?

I've been thinking about using `type: logrotate`, different handlers for each type I want, and saving them into separate files, but I don't like how extensive the bundle looks like, the idea of handlers which seems confusing (what's main, what's nested...), and the lack of good documentation.

Comment: How many pageviews per second do you need to handle?

Comment: About 20 requests per second.

Comment: Then you don't need to worry about performance. Just use Monolog's default file log and configure logrotate at system level. When you get 50+ pageviews per second, consider using something different than file log, e.g. Sentry, Graylog, or any other UDP/TCP-based system (there's a plenty of choices, self-hosted and SaaS solutions, most of them are supported by Monolog).